# Printing the first element in LinkedList java

Tags: java

Everything is working fine int he given code, except that the display does not print the first most inserted element

```
 public void display()
    {
    Link pcurrent = pfirst;
    while(pcurrent.next!= null)
    {
      System.out.println(pcurrent);
      pcurrent = pcurrent.next;

    }
    }
```

with elements inserted in order : `100, 200, 300, 400`->
It outputs them as:

```
//nothing in first turn 
200 
300, 200 (in second iteration)
400, 300, 200 in last iteration
```

How do I change this?

What I want is this:

```
 100
  200, 100
  300, 200, 100
  400, 300, 200, 100
```

Comment: Swap printing and assignment lines.

Comment: @PM77-1 - Not enough. Also needs to change the `while` condition and (if printing `pfirst` is supposed to be suppressed) also changing the initialization before the loop.

Comment: Depends on what this is being used for, but if you want to be fancy you can implement iterable and that will make your loops more readable and 1-off error free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your code, you first advancing the pointer then trying to print the value. Just swap the statements in `while` loop. If you want to print whole list, you should also change the condition of `while` loop.

```
  public void display() {
        Link pcurrent = pfirst;
        while(pcurrent!= null) {
                System.out.println(pcurrent);
                pcurrent = pcurrent.next;
         }
   }
```

Comment: Looks remarkably like my answer (once one reads the final paragraph). :)

Answer (score 1):

From your code, it seems that you intentionally want to skip printing `pfirst`. If so, try this:

```
public void display()
{
    Link pcurrent = pfirst.next;
    while(pcurrent!= null)
    {
        System.out.println(pcurrent);
        pcurrent = pcurrent.next;
    }
}
```

Here, I've changed how `pcurrent` is initialized before the loop, changed the loop condition, and changed the order of events inside the loop body.

This should perhaps be better done as a `for` loop:

```
for (Link pcurrent = pfirst.next; pcurrent != null; pcurrent = pcurrent.next) {
    System.out.println(pcurrent);
}
```

If you also want to print `pfirst` (which sounds like what you actually want to do), then just keep the initialization of `pcurrent` as you currently have it and still make the other changes.

Comment: starting it from pfirst.next gives NullPointerException as well and yes I want to print pfirst as well and  I shifted the print line before transitioning to next element, doing that did not help either because now I does print the last element inserted but not the first most element

Comment: @GurupratapSaini - Did you change the `while` loop test? If so, I can't see how this could give a NPE.

Comment: If you want to print whole list, check my answer

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are inserting the element in the front of the list.
Swap your statement in the while loop.

```
void print(list *head)
{
    list *pcurrent = head;
    while(head != NULL)
    {
      System.out.println(pcurrent);
      pcurrent = pcurrent.next;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will fail to print the last element. You've replaced one problem with another.